# If multiple columns in text file bash scripting

Tags: bash

How to detect multiple columns inside if statement for bash scripting? I want to do something if there are multiple columns inside the text file.

Example:

I will output one command to file device.txt

If there is only one device, I will have just that name inside the document:

```
Device1:
```

If I have multiple devices I will have this inside the device.txt file:

```
Device1: Device2: Device3:
```

I want to create if statement inside my bash script that will be triggered if there are multiple devices.

Comment: Your question is too imprecise without even sample data and code showing your intent.

Comment: ok i will try to update now, but i thkin that it is clear what i want to do

Comment: @LéaGris i update the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i use this command 
`wc -w` it do just what i need

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ `awk 'NF > 1' device.txt` ]]; then
    command
fi
```

`awk` while start printing anything whenever the number of fields of a line exceeds one.

You could make it more elegant by using `{exit 1}` as the `awk` command to execute whenever the condition applies, but it does make it harder to understand what's going on, as than there is 'false' exit code when the condition applied, since finding no columns results in a 'successful` execution of the awk program.

Comment: You don't need the double brackets and the backticks: `if awk '{exit ! (NF > 1)}' device.txt; then`

Comment: I try this on my file, and that didnt give me results i need, but ty for help so much u inspire me for some other things <3